# R smartly deciding about par-mfrow in a function

Tags: r, par

I want to print output, according to the amount of variables that have more than 10 unique values in a data-frame. This could be any number of variables. I am looking for a way to implement this as to set the plot window to be perfect for the amount of variables.

It kind of should be like:

- 2 vars -> 1 by 2
- 3 vars -> 1 by 3
- 4 vars -> 2 by 2
- 5 vars -> 2 by 3
- 6 vars -> 2 by 3
- .....
- .....
- 16 vars  -> 4 by 4
- 16+ vars -> 4 by 4

Is there a logical formula for this;

How to make this into a succesful `par(mfrow=(c(x,y)))`?

Also, how to make sure when the par limit has been reached, to `click` for the next window, I can't click when I have more than 16, but instead just overwrites the previous graphs.

Comment: I am not really understanding what you want to achieve. It sounds like you would like to facet a plot? If so, you could [use ggplot2](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Facets%20%28ggplot2%29/).

Comment: @Roland Not all functions/packages use **ggplot2** for their plotting and faceting is not the same as what `mfrow` does to the plot device.

Comment: None of the answers below seem to address the question of using a click to proceed to the next plot when the plot number is >16.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I am well aware of that and often use base graphics myself. But as I said, I don't even understand the question. The first sentence could mean a lot of things.

Comment: @Marcinthebox You can't easily do that. `locator(1)` in a loop called if loop index > 16, 32 etc will force user to click plot. `devAskNewPage()` can be used for a prompt in the console.

Comment: @Marcinthebox I've updated my answer along the lines I mentioned above. Easier than I thought...

Comment: @GavinSimpson - looks great Gavin. Didn't realize that `locator`could be used. I knoew there must be something out there along the lines of `devAskNewPage` but couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: Why did the answer get five upvotes and the question just one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Getting the number of rows and columns for the device

The `n2mfrow()` was designed for this purpose, although it tends to vary rows faster than columns so is opposite of what you want. For example:

```
> n2mfrow(2)
[1] 2 1
```

indicates 2 rows by 1 column. Of course, `rev()` makes it easy to get the output you want:

```
> rev(n2mfrow(3))
[1] 1 3
```

Here is output from `n2mfrow()` for 2 to 16 total plots with columns varying faster:

```
t(sapply(2:16, function(x) rev(n2mfrow(x))))

> t(sapply(2:16, function(x) rev(n2mfrow(x))))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    2    2
 [4,]    2    3
 [5,]    2    3
 [6,]    3    3
 [7,]    3    3
 [8,]    3    3
 [9,]    3    4
[10,]    3    4
[11,]    3    4
[12,]    4    4
[13,]    4    4
[14,]    4    4
[15,]    4    4
```

### Making this interactive

For the "click after 16" bit. If doing your plotting in a `for(i in numplots)` loop, when `i` > 16 call `devAskNewPage(ask = TRUE)` and that will prompt for user to active next plot.

For example:

```
np <- 18 ## number of plots
rc <- ifelse(np > 16, 16, np)
op <- par(mfrow = rev(n2mfrow(rc)))
for(i in seq_len(np)) {
  if(i == 2) {
    devAskNewPage(ask = TRUE)
  }
  plot(1:10)
}
par(op)
devAskNewPage(ask = FALSE)
```

A similar thing could be done using `locator(1)` to force a click to move on post 16 plots, but it needs a bit more work:

```
np <- 18 ## number of plots
rc <- ifelse(np > 16, 16, np)
op <- par(mfrow = rev(n2mfrow(rc)))
for(i in seq_len(np)) {
  if((i %% 16) + 1 == 2 && i > 1) {
    message("Page filled. Click on device to continue...")
    locator(1)
  }
  plot(1:10)
}
par(op)
```

Comment: It might even be that not using `rev()` should be preferred. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: if you want regions with unequal size `layout()` function provides an alternative..

Comment: I got the devAskNewPage working. In my case I had to subtract the cases of the for loop integer `i - the amount of ordinal variables %% 16 == 0`.

Comment: @Dualinity with `devAskNewPage()` you only need to call it once as it only affects a new page of the device not a plot window. See my updated Answer - you only need to turn it on after plot 1 is done. If you set it before the loop, then you get asked before the first plot is drawn which is not what we want.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Gotcha. Changed to: `if ((i - ord) == 16) {devAskNewPage(ask = TRUE)}` (within the loop)

Comment: I used this now for some time, but I am not satisfied. I would like it to continue running the code, so I would like it to process everything and not wait. Only the plot window should wait. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: @Dualinity No, that isn't possible to the best of my knowledge as R doesn't return control until you've clicked etc. You could use the plot history mechanism, draw all plots and then page back through them. But that is another Question.